# Help me remove this Bash error

Tags: bash, bashrc

The bash error below keeps popping up each time I open a new terminal, why is that?

- How do I fix the bash error below?

  ```
  bash: /home/yonas/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
  ```

Comment: Edit your `~/.bashrc` and remove the offending instance of that file. Should be right at the end of the .bashrc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was installing RVM on a remote server today and had the same issue. It seems that the installation was not executed by default. This is what I did to solve it:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

  # In case rvm not found
  cd ~/.rvm/archives
  tar xvzf rvm-1.26.0.tgz # or whatever RVM version you have
  cd mpapis-rvm-xxxxxxx
  ./install
  cd ..
  rm -Rf mpapis-rvm-xxxxxxxx

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

- original answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747258/install-rvm-bash-root-rvm-scripts-rvm-no-such-file-or-directory)